# Как обновить данные в MySQL, не затрагивая те, которые уже установлены?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как обновить данные в MySQL, не затрагивая те, которые уже установлены? То есть:
[image]
Поле xfields необходимо обновить, так чтобы все старые данные остались.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE `table` SET `xfields`= CONCAT(`xfields`, '-', '99')  WHERE id = 1

Comment: сурово, я вообще ничего не понял в вопросе)))))

Comment: Как я понял, нужно к текущему значению добавить новые. 
Но если нужно проверить на дубляж внутри поля, то вытаскивать и сравнивать.
p.s. атомарность полей мы не чтем :)

Comment: и лучше хранить тогда в json-формате, удобней преобразовывать потом.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE имя_таблицы
CHANGE xfields новое_имя_поля_если_надо int(10) unsigned NULL AFTER имя_поля_после которого_разместить_это_поле, COMMENT='';`

Только естественно замените `int(10) unsigned NULL` на то, что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Просто получать значение поля xfields, а потом дополнять его новыми значениями. Соответственно при редактировании(UPDATE table) указать xfields ='$xfields_plus'.

```
$xfields_plus = $data['xfields'].'|bla|blabla';
```

А если и еще что-то заменить, то preg_replace() или str_replace() Вам в помощь.